# Babel - Different transpilation results when exporting es modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

Let's say I have two es modules **myModule/A** and **myModule/B** and I want to export them in my **myModule/index** file. I have to approches to do so:

#### - Approch A:

```
// myModule/index.es
import moduleA from './A';
import moduleB from './B';
export { moduleA, moduleB };
```

Babel will transpile the code like below:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.moduleB = exports.moduleA = undefined;

var _A = require('./A');

var _A2 = _interopRequireDefault(_A);

var _B = require('./B');

var _B2 = _interopRequireDefault(_B);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

exports.moduleA = _A2.default;
exports.moduleB = _B2.default;
```

#### - Approch B:

```
// myModule/index.es
export { default as moduleA } from './A';
export { default as moduleB } from './B';
```

Babel will transpile the code like below:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _A = require('./A');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'moduleA', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_A).default;
  }
});

var _B = require('./B');

Object.defineProperty(exports, 'moduleB', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _interopRequireDefault(_B).default;
  }
});

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Can anyone explain why we have different results?. Thank you!

Comment: I can't comment on Babel or whether it correctly reflects the ES6 semantics, but a major difference is that approach A will introduce `moduleA` and `moduleB` as local variables in the module while approach B won't.

Answer (score 3):

They are different results because Babel 6 does a bad job of compiling these cases. In Babel 7.x, the module transformation plugins were rewritten from scratch and two examples produce identical output with that, as

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "moduleA", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _A.default;
  }
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "moduleB", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _B.default;
  }
});

var _A = _interopRequireDefault(require("./A"));

var _B = _interopRequireDefault(require("./B"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

As noted by [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), the only functional difference between the two is that the first will create local variables named `moduleA` and `moduleB`, but since your example code never tries to use those imported variables anyway, there is no difference in the output.